# Initialization of multidimensional array in class

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a Tetris clone in C++ and I want to store the pieces in a multidimensional array. I declare it in my header file like this:

```
class Pieces
{

public:
  Pieces();

private:
   int pieces[7][4][5][5];

};
```

And I'm trying to initialize it in the constructor:

```
Pieces::Pieces()
{
  pieces[7][4][5][5] = { /* ... all of the pieces go in here ... */ };
}
```

But this doesn't work and I get an error like this:

```
src/Pieces.cpp:5:17: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int’ in assignment
```

How can I declare and initialize this array?

Comment: Put `pieces` in the member initializer list of the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11:

```
Pieces::Pieces()
    : pieces{ /* ... all of the pieces go in here ... */ }
{

}
```

In C++03:

```
Pieces::Pieces()
{
    // iterate over all fields and assign each one separately
}
```